# How to push a route with different params?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Hi I am trying to push a page but it appears any push to a page I'm currently on doesn't reload the page like /about to /about doesn't do anything(which is fine). If I push a page that is different than the one I'm on it will direct me to the page and reload(expected). The problem is I am using a param in the url that affects what is shown like /profile/jordan1 and when I push /profile/jordan2 because its the same base route and only parameter change it does show /profile/jordan2 in the URL but does not actually reload the page so the page doesn't repopulate with jordan2 data and stays unchanged so I can reload the browser myself and it will work but I want the button click to do that like it should do

Im using Vuetify and have tried just using :to in the button component as well as @click and creating a method with

```
:to="'/profile/' + this.$store.state.userAuthData.username"
```

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'Profile', params: { username: this.$store.state.userAuthData.username } })
```

both work Identical and have same issue.(the :to one I'm actually using a computed property with that route but for simplicity just wrote it like this)

Comment: Try adding a `key` to the `<router-view>` component to force a replacement like so: `<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>`

Comment: Wow! yeah that works. Quick response, simple solution, what a time to be alive. I appreciate you

Comment: I might create a Q&A in here to reference similar questions, in the meantime... what this tells Vue is: If the full path changes, **even if the component is the same**, you should render it from scratch. Vue always tries to reuse components to increase performance, but in this case we do not want that. Read [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) to know what the `key` attribute does.

Comment: @Ricky Thanks. Was reading lot of stuffs, your answer is the only one really helping.